# Post Kendo Multiselect values to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I seem to be having a problem posting the selected values from my Kendo Multiselect widget to an action on my controller. I've never had this issue before and as far as I know I am doing everything right, but something is obviously causing an issue.

I have this input on my view:

```
<input id="ProductHandlingTypes" name="ProductHandlingTypes" style="width: 100%"/>
```

My `ViewModel`

```
public class BuyerProfileViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BuyerTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<int> ProductHandlingTypes { get; set; }

    public bool Producer { get; set; }
}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$("#ProductHandlingTypes").kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: "-- Select Type(s) --",
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Helper/GetProductHandlingTypes",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET"
            }
        }
    })
});

$("#btnSave").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formCreate = $(".form-register-buyer");
    formCreate.validate();

    if (formCreate.valid()) {
        var options = {
            url: $(formCreate).attr("action"),
            type: $(formCreate).attr("method"),
            data: $(formCreate).serialize()
        };

        $.ajax(options)
            .done(function(data) {
                if (data.success === true) {
                    window.location.href = data.redirectTo;
                } else {
                    toastr.options = { "postiionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width" };
                    toastr.error(data.message, "Uh, Oh!");
                }
            });
    }
});
```

When I submit my form to the controller I can see that all of the correct values are being passed except for `ProductHandlingTypes`. It just says it has a count of 1 and when I expand it out it says 0.

Comment: It needs to be `<select id="ProductHandlingTypes" name="ProductHandlingTypes" multiple style="width: 100%"><select>` so that an array of values is posted.

Comment: Wow I'm not sure how I missed that. Thanks though!

Comment: This helped me too as I was using asp-for tag helpers which just don't seem to work at all with kendo multiselect